# error Attributeerror: 'nonetype' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter

Soy nuevo en el mundo del `tkinter`, y quería aprender más así que decidí hacer un pequeño programa para calcular volumenes.

Pero este tiene un problema denominado como `attributeerror`, les comparto el código para que por favor me puedan ayudar.

He intentado múltiples soluciones, y la verdad es que no he podido solucionar este problema, y es el único problema que se me presenta a lo largo del programa.

```
import tkinter
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from gui import interfaz

input_text=str()
ventana = tkinter.Toplevel()
path1="/home/chucho/Documentos/calculadora_volumenes/imagenes/volumencubo.png"
ancho_label = 15
alto_label = 2
var=tkinter.StringVar(ventana)
mystring=tkinter.StringVar(ventana)
dato=tkinter.StringVar(ventana)
result=tkinter.StringVar()
x=None
y=None
z=None

def create_frame():
    ventana.title("CALCULADORA DE VOLÚMENES")
    #ventana.iconbitmap(r"/home/chucho/Documentos/calculadora_volumenes/imagenes/Calculator_30001.ico")
    ventana.geometry("600x800")
    ventana.resizable(False,False)
    ventana.config(bg="gray")

    lbl=tkinter.Label(ventana,text="VOLÚMEN DEL CUBO")
    lbl.config(font="Arial")
    lbl.pack(anchor="center")

    text=tkinter.Label(ventana,text="volumen cubo= lado x lado x lado")
    text.pack(anchor="center")

    img_cubo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path1))
    cubo=tkinter.Label(ventana,image=img_cubo,height=200,width=300)
    cubo.place(x=150, y=100)

    cuadro1 = tkinter.Entry(ventana, font=("arial",20,),width=22, textvariable=var, insertwidth=10, bg="white", justify="right")
    cuadro1.place(x=200, y=350)
    lbl1 = tkinter.Label(ventana, text="Lado 1= ", width=ancho_label, height=alto_label)
    lbl1.place(x=75, y=352)
    x=cuadro1
    print(var)

    cuadro2 = tkinter.Entry(ventana, font=("arial",20,),width=22, textvariable=dato, insertwidth=10, bg="white", justify="right")
    cuadro2.place(x=200, y=420)
    lbl2 = tkinter.Label(ventana, text="Lado 2= ", width=ancho_label, height=alto_label)
    lbl2.place(x=75, y=422)
    y=cuadro2
    print(dato)

    cuadro3 = tkinter.Entry(ventana, font=("arial",20,),width=22, textvariable=mystring, insertwidth=10, bg="white", justify="right")
    cuadro3.place(x=200, y=490)
    lbl3 = tkinter.Label(ventana, text="Lado 3= ", width=ancho_label, height=alto_label)
    lbl3.place(x=75, y=492)
    z=cuadro3
    print(mystring)

    botoncalcular = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="CALCULAR", bg="white", width=10, height=2, command=vol_cubo)
    botoncalcular.place(x=250, y=560)

    cuadroresultado = tkinter.Entry(ventana, font=("arial",20,),width=22, textvariable=result, insertwidth=10, bg="white", justify="right")
    cuadroresultado.place(x=200, y=630)
    lblresultado = tkinter.Label(ventana, text="RESULTADO= ", width=ancho_label, height=alto_label)
    lblresultado.place(x=75, y=632)

    botonregresar = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="REGRESAR", bg="white", width=10, height=2, command=regresar)
    botonregresar.place(x=250, y=700)

    ventana.mainloop()

def vol_cubo():
    global x
    global y 
    global z
    print("hola")
    volumen_cubo=int(x.get())*int(y.get())*int(z.get())
    return var.set(volumen_cubo)

def regresar():
    interfaz.create_frame()
```

El código de error completo que me arroja es el siguiente

```
PY_VAR0
PY_VAR2
PY_VAR1
hola
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/chucho/Documentos/calculadora_volumenes/gui/cubo.py", line 76, in vol_cubo
    volumen_cubo=int(x.get())*int(y.get())*int(z.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Ese `py_var0`, `py_var1` y `py_var2` me lo arroja  cuando declaro el print para verificar que si este opteniendo un dato y no un `None`.

Espero por favor me puedan ayudar dando solución a mi problema.

Comment: El valor de las variables globales *x*, *y*, *z* es `None`. Dentro de la función `create_frame` declara `global x, y, z`. Un saludo!

Comment: Existen varias vías de solución para esta situación, pero respetando tu código, lo primero que debes hacer es declarar en `create_frame` que las variables `x`, `y`, `z` son globales (es decir, no es necesario que lo pongas en `vol_cubo`, aunque si lo haces no te dará error, pero sí es necesario ponerlo en `create_frame`). Además, si quieres que se muestre el resultado, en `vol_cubo` debes cambiar `return var.set(volumen_cubo)` por `result.set(volumen_cubo)` (recuerda que no es necesario que el método retorne algo, aunque si pones `return result.set(volumen_cubo)`, te funcionará igual)

Comment: Gracias , ya aplique lo que me dijeron y el programa corre a las mil maravillas, muchas gracias, un saludo!